# What's the joke in Lee's words?

Tags: meaning, jokes

In *The Kissing Booth 2 (2020)*, Elle and Lee asks Marco to be kisser at the kissing booth:

> Elle: It's the most popular booth! And it's for charity. Don't you
> believe  in charity?
>
> Marco: **I'm standing here talking to you**.
>
> Lee: Hey! Whoo-hoo-hoo! That was a good... one.
>
> (Lee high fives with Marco)

What's the joke in Lee's words?

Comment: Marco is making a joke that it's charity work to be keeping Elle company.

Comment: As answered by other posters. Lee is not making a joke. Lee is responding to Marco's intentionally mean-spirited and sarcastic joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elle asks

> Don't you believe in charity?

and Marco responds

> I'm standing here talking to you.

You could even tack on a "aren't I?" for a greater emphasis. In other words, he is implying that his charity is talking to her as no one would want to talk to her otherwise.